# How to encrypt text on one device and decrypt it on another device?

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption

I'm using React Native to make an app that sends text from Device A to Server to Device B. I'm trying to implement some sort of encryption between for the transaction, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I've looked at several libraries and packages like [RSA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rsa), but I don't understand it very well.

If User A has a private key and a public key, and User B has their own private and public keys, how would they be able to communicate if User A does not have User B's public key and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

They couldn't.

The point of public keys is that you share them (hence "public").

If you don't share them, public key encryption doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand, if User A and User B share their public keys with the Server, will I be able to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Since you want A and B to communicate, they need to share their keys with *each other*. The server doesn't need the keys because it doesn't need to encrypt the data.